# Create a php class from multiple files

Tags: php, class, modular-design

I would like to forge a class, from functions inside different php files. Something like this would be possible?

The goal is to create a modular class, which then can be used to upgrade the admin surface of an existing system.

Traits might be the answer.
How could I dynamically look for them?
I know where they will be found but thats it.

Right now I jumped back into the drawing board, get_declared_traits() is the thing whats probably gonna solve it for me.

Comment: Yes. It possible. You want php Traits: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: actually the question is abstract , specify your needs and your work here.

i think u are talking about inheritance like stuff..
we can derive the quality of a class to another using inheritance..
then you refer [http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Comment: Inheritance won't solve it.

The trait was the exact thing what I was looking for.

Altough, there is one catch: I know the folders where the traits will be found, but thats all what I know. would it still be solvable?